# Store customer data into a binary file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am creating a banking system in c++. I have created all the functions like   deposit,withdraw.Different account types: saving and current. But dont know how to store the data in a binary file. Also i want that the data entered in one session must be present for use in the other. Can you please suggest me something how to do it?

Comment: [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), [`std::ios_base::binary`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)

Comment: Can u specify how to write using these?

Comment: @Angew That won't make the file contents binary; it only controls the format at the OS level.

Comment: THen how i have to do it?

Comment: @Angew Note that if this is a real bank application (and not some homework), he probably cannot use `std::filebuf`, since it doesn't support transactional integrity.

Comment: file handling > http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/Files1.html  for binary files  > http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html

Comment: @dotNetSoldier I'd avoid that "tutorial" if I were you.  It doesn't actually explain anything, and contains at least one blatant error.  (It says that `pos_type` is an integral type; the standard does not allow it to be an integral type.)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier _NO_.  That site is horrible.  The author doesn't know C++ IO at all.  (For example, it contains a `while ( !stream.eof() )`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I didnt read any of them ,it was just a quick search result ,thanks for pointing out let me remove it.

Comment: You need to learn file handling in C++ ,there are many tutorials available.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier But how many good ones?  Doing quality IO in C++ is easier than in any other language I know, but the quality of the tutorials I've seen on the net makes me think that it isn't well known.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well I think you are right,I have a very limited amount of C++ experience ,if you think there are no good tutes then why not make one for us and share it :)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Time.  I've actually started on one, but I only find time to work on it about once every three months.

Answer (score 3):

First: why binary?  Binary files are usually not a good idea.

If it does have to be binary, you'll have to start by defining
a binary format: how you want to represent each type in the
file.  Binary does *not* mean unformatted.  Unless there are
good reasons for doing otherwise, you might start with an
already defined format, such as XDR.  Then you should probably
define stream types for reading and writing this
format—the input and output functions in `std::istream`
and `std::ostream` either use text format, or are unformatted
(which means you have to manually format or unformat the data
you give it or receive from it).  It's probably a good idea to
have these classes derive from `std::basic_ios<char>`, however;
it has a lot which will be superflous (e.g. the formatting
flags), but it will provide a more or less standard error
reporting mechanism.  And you can (and probably should) use the
standard `streambuf`, just ensure that with `filebuf`, the file
is opened in binary mode, and the `filebuf` itself is imbued
with the `"C"` locale.

Alternatively, you can format into an `std::vector<unsigned
char>`, and use the system level functions to do the writing.
In fact, you may have to do this, since `filebuf` cannot be made
transactionally secure.  If this is a real bank application,
and not course work, you *will* have to do this, because real
bank applications do require transactional integrity: you have
to open the file with special arguments, to ensure that you
don't return from a write until the data is physically on disk.
And none of the standard streams support this.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain in an easier way. Because i have just started file handling in C++.

Comment: @user861938 I'm afraid there is no easier way.  Outputting a binary format is complex, and requires a fair amount of understanding of what you're doing.  (Just defining the format requires a significant amount of knowledge, but you could just use XDR.)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Except that it's not a little code.  Or rather: the code isn't all that long, but to understand it supposes a fairly good understanding of how iostream itself is organized: the roles of the base classes and the streambuf, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you're trying to do is actually serialization. 
Good libraries to do this are [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Boost.Serialization is a complex monster with lots of caveats to consider, but for your simple case it should be fairly easy to do. Protocol Buffers requires some more work from a maintenance perspective (you have to maintain a .proto file that describes the format of what you're saving).

I can go into a lot of detail here about how each library works but I suggest you look at the documentation to see which one suits you best. Personally, I used to work with Boost.Serialization a lot but because of all the caveats I moved to Protocol Buffers (also be cause I use it to transfer objects between Java and C++).

With these libraries you can easily save the objects in binary format, without worrying too much about the details. At a later point, you can also easily switch to an XML or text output.